# How to obtain a client-side token without using Stripe's UI layer?

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I have the following php page that works fine:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>
    <script>
        var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
          key: '<?=$stripePublicKey?>',
          image: 'https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png',
          locale: 'auto',
          token: function(token) {
            // You can access the token ID with `token.id`.
            // Get the token ID to your server-side code for use.
            console.log("token.id: " + token.id);
            console.log("token: " + token);
          }
        });

        function init(){
            document.getElementById('customButton').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                // Open Checkout with further options:
                handler.open({
                    name: 'TruckerCert',
                    description: 'Buy Certs',
                    amount: 2000
                });
                e.preventDefault();
            });

            // Close Checkout on page navigation:
            window.addEventListener('popstate', function() {
              handler.close();
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
<h1>Stripe Token Test</h1>
<button id="customButton">Purchase</button>
</body>
</html>
```

It works and produces the following JSON:

```
{
  "id": "tok_1E255j2*****wC135im",
  "object": "token",
  "card": {
    "id": "card_1E255j2H1*****RGS4Kqc",
    "object": "card",
    "address_city": null,
    "address_country": null,
    "address_line1": null,
    "address_line1_check": null,
    "address_line2": null,
    "address_state": null,
    "address_zip": null,
    "address_zip_check": null,
    "brand": "Visa",
    "country": "US",
    "customer": null,
    "cvc_check": "pass",
    "dynamic_last4": null,
    "exp_month": 12,
    "exp_year": 2021,
    "fingerprint": "3nk5B*****29xV",
    "funding": "unknown",
    "last4": "1111",
    "metadata": {
    },
    "name": "her*******@gmail.com",
    "tokenization_method": null,
    "type": "Visa"
  },
  "client_ip": "67.***.***.17",
  "created": 1549754315,
  "email": "her********@gmail.com",
  "livemode": false,
  "type": "card",
  "used": false
}
```

So that is all as expected. The problem is, the only way I can find to submit my credit card # and exp date and receive back the JSON is by going through their UI. For example, when I click my `customButton`, this dialog appears:

[image]

I don't want to use their cc form. I have my own CC form. I want to use my own form, send an ajax request to Stripe's API endpoint, and receive back the JSON just as above. I have combed through Stripe's online docs for an hour and can't find any way to do this.

How is it done?

Comment: If you use your own form how are you going to ensure you are PCI compliant?

Comment: Quite easily: If Stripe had an endpoint for ajax usage (do they?), certainly that goes over SSL, and if I send the sensitive data over SSL to their endpoint, and get back only tokens and non-sensitive data, then PCI compliance has been achieved. In fact this is precisely how Authorize.net's Accept.js works, and they are 100% PCI compliant. Authnet's way of doing it enables pure customization in the hands of the dev while being PCI compliant, and I'm looking for something similar in Stripe. The only reason I don't use authnet is this is for my own little company, and authnet charges monthlies.

Comment: Just posted an answer, but Stripe doesn't support that, without using an older version of Stripe.js. Which is not recommended at all. You should use Stripe Elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The product you mentioned is called [Stripe Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout) and lets you collect card details securely without having to build your own payment form.

Since you mentioned having your payment form already though you should instead look into [Stripe Elements](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js#elements). This lets you design and style your own payment form while still meeting the lowest level of PCI compliance, SAQ A, as [documented here](https://stripe.com/docs/security#validating-pci-compliance).

You can still multiple examples of payments form and the corresponding code here: https://stripe.github.io/elements-examples/

Comment: I spent time studying Stripe elements and it seems they're heavily UI-specific to Stripe's way of doing things, and it would be a lot of work to use my own form without a complete rewrite. I was hoping to avoid that.

Comment: Do they really not have an endpoint that I can make ajax calls to, to get back a token?

Comment: The issue here is PCI compliance. You do not want to do what you describe to avoid breaking the PCI rules that's all.

Comment: Not at all true. Authorize.net does exactly what I'm describing, they're larger than Stripe, and they are 100% PCI compliant.

Comment: @HerrimanCoder You are mixing things here though. It's not that Authorize.net is not PCI compliance, it's that you would not be. Or rather you would have a higher scope for PCI compliance in that case and have to figure out SAQ A-EP instead which you are unlikely to want. That's all. You should use Elements to fall under SAQ A and not run into any trouble.

Comment: I agree I'll need to use Elements with Stripe. My point is that Authnet doesn't assume that all developers are fraudsters as Stripe apparently does, and go to great lengths to shield the CC# from being touched by the dev. That seems silly because if the devs really wanted to steal numbers, there are many ways they could still do that. Authnet focuses on keeping the CC out of the hands of hackers, not out of the hands of developers.

Comment: This has nothing to do with being a fraudster though and is here to protect most developers that would not realize the implications of doing it wrong really. Stripe has supported the other approach for a long time and it's still supported https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/v2

Answer (score 1):

Stripe.js version 2 supported this. As of the time of writing this you can see the old documentation [here](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/v2). If I had to guess Stripe.js v2 will be depreciated fully and removed from use at some point. So although you can use it with some hassle, it is depreciated, and you have to ask yourself if it's worth the risk of having to rewrite in the future. Since you are building it currently, I would just use the latest technology.

Also, according to [Stripe's page on PCI compliance](https://stripe.com/docs/security#validating-pci-compliance):

> If you continue to use Stripe.js v2, you’ll be required to upload your SAQ A-EP annually to prove your business is PCI compliant.

---

Overall using Stripe's Elements system is the way to go. There is no way you can touch the user's payment information, which makes it as secure as possible. Much less possibility of you messing up in your code vs an AJAX call. What if you accidentally send the AJAX call to your own server? You are in violation of PCI compliance then.

Stripe Elements also provides a LOT of customization in terms of styling. You should be able to design it in a way that integrates with your existing form pretty easily.